# how can i know and change url when i try to get out of router-view in vue

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vue-router

I am Korean, so I hope you could understand it with my awkward English skills

I am studying about vue and router and i face to some problem

here is my source code

```
{path: '/conference-detail/:id/:Step', component: () => import('..), props: true, children: 
[
        {path: '/conference-detail/:id/:Step/step1', name: 'StepOne', component: () => import('..')},
        {path: '/conference-detail/:id/:Step/step2', name: 'StepTwo', component: () => import('..')},
        {path: '/conference-detail/:id/:Step/step3', name: 'StepThree', component: () => import('..')},
        {path: '/conference-detail/:id/:Step/step4', name: 'StepFour', component: () => import('..')},
    ]},

         <template v-for="(item, index) in processList">
            <router-link
              :to="{name: item.name}"
              :key="index"
              v-text="item.text"
              class="step"
              active-class="active"
              />
          </template>

<router-view/>
```

I want to get url without "step1, step2..." in children path when I get out of children component
just like "/conference-detail/:id/:Step"
I think its like removing child component from parent component..

I hope you get it what I am want to try

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a problem in the last two lines :

```
<template v-for="(item, index) in processList">
            <router-link
              :to="{name: item.name}"
              :key="index"
              v-text="item.text"
              class="step"
              active-class="active"
              />
                
             </router-view>
          </template>
```